# loading script only once on click event

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, typeof, getelementsbytagname

I've hacked together vanilla javascript to load external script on click event.

```
var searchLabel = document.getElementById('search-toggle-label');
searchLabel.onclick = function(){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "wp-content/themes/2016/js/cse.js."; 
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    return false;
}
```

But it keeps loading the same script every time on click event.

So I threw in an if statement to check for value & type. "==="

```
var searchLabel = document.getElementById('search-toggle-label');
if (typeof searchLabel === 'undefined') {
    searchLabel.onclick = function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "wp-content/themes/2016/js/cse.js."; 
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    alert('loaded already');
}
```

Obviously, this is wrong since I get an alert on page load & on click event, the script does not load.

I am stumped. I know there is an easy solution using jQuery but I am trying to actually learn to write javascript.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want it to do? Only load the script on the first click?

Comment: Yes.  Only load the script on the first click & not on subsequent clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the event listener once it has fired:

```
var searchLabel = document.getElementById('search-toggle-label');
searchLabel.addEventListener('click', loadScript('wp-content/themes/2016/js/cse.js'), false);

function loadScript(src){
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src; 
    document.head.append(script);
    return searchLabel.removeEventListener('click', loadScript, false);
}
```

Comment: Sorry David Walsh.  Your wrapper works nicely but the above script is more succinct for me.  So I am going with Malk.  

Thanks!!  I actually had tried to add .removeEventLister & I see why it didn't work; because I was trying to remove it before it fired.

Comment: very useful and compact! I made some changes to make everything even more streamlined, hope you appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to return true/false for if a script is present in the DOM. Here is one:

```
function isScriptLoaded(src) {
  return !!Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('script'), function(node) {
    return node.src === src;
  });
}
```

Then use that to test if the script is already inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Nope.  

Not quite sure what you mean by "match the suffix/end of the script src" but your regular expression? "srcSuffix$" (not sure what this is) fails to prevent subsequent loading of the script.

Comment: @HackYa Yeah, I made a mistake there -- I'll fix it.

Comment: @HackYa I've fixed that mistake

Comment: What I meant though is if you set a relative `src`, the browser is probably going to expand it to include the protocol, host, etc. So if you just want to match what you set, you'd test the end of the node `src` matched not the whole `src` (to match whole source, have to pass in more).

Comment: But good news is it doesn't work that way with Chrome -- the src is the relative one. I updated to keep it simple and clean.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks.  However, as stated above, simply removing the EventlListner seems/feels like the most logical thing to do here.

Comment: @HackYa Yeah, definitely -- I was assuming you'd be using it for something else (like wanted click to still do something else too). I didn't read more though so if that works, it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set a flag before the function definition. That way you can check the flag at the start of the function and omit the rest. You also have a great example I found on the internet. Look up this [solution](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once).

Comment: Thanks. Did use David Walsh's wrapper function & it does work.  However, Malk's approach of removing the EventlListner seems more right to me?

Comment: You are right, that approach is better. So go with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to load the script synchronously (and only once):

```
const isScriptLoaded = (src)=>{
  const scripts = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('script')) || []
  return scripts.filter((node) => node.src && node.src.indexOf(src)>-1).length>0
}

const loadScript = (src, once=true)=>{
  if (once && isScriptLoaded(src)) return

  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    const node = document.createElement('script')
    node.setAttribute('src', src)
    node.onload = ()=>{ 
      setTimeout(()=>{ resolve() }, 0)
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node)
  })
}
```

Then, in your vue component:

```
  ...

  async mounted () {
    await loadScript('/js/globe.min.js') // wait for the script to be loaded
    // this.scriptIsReadyLetsDoSomethingWithIt()
    
    // Will do nothing if you call loadScript multiple times (as the script is already loaded)
    // await loadScript('/js/globe.min.js')
    
  },
  ...
```